# Fitting an ornate ceiling rose

Tags: ceiling, light-fixture

I've got to fit a ceiling rose. I'd assumed that the centre would be clear so that I could fit a ceiling rose hook for the chandelier. However, it's decorative all the way to the centre like this :

[image: see here]

Any advice on how to attach the chandelier chain?

Comment: What is the material the rose is made of, and what is the diameter of the finished escutcheon of the chandelier, as well as the electric box in the ceiling? I may be misunderstanding the mounting though. It sounds like the chandelier is to be hung "swag" style. It may be the wrong term, but it means the electric connection is not going to be in the center of the rose, it will be just the light only, the electric connection is in another location aside from the rose you plan to install.

Comment: be very helpful to see the light mounting details. What you do with the rose is totally dependent on what is required for the light support and electrical feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the usual idea is you cut out the size hole you require. There are multiple circular features you can follow when cutting at various sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to drill out a hole in the centre of the ceiling rose - about 2cm or 3cm diameter should be enough - to bring the electric cables through from the roof cavity. Drill out the hole before you mount the ceiling rose to the ceiling. Then you need to fasten the chandelier through the same hole to a batten or other fixture point using wire or chain.